# Using Google transit in Web Application

Tags: python, django, google-maps, real-time, transit

I'm working on my last semester project which is based on real-time transit. So, I want to develop website (using Python + Django Fw) that will show all our university buses' real-time Geo-location (**Google map API** or any other **please suggest the best one**) to the university students and professors, and also shows the bus arrival times for bus stop nearest to them (From wherever they are). This is main module of my project. So the question is that

- May I use Google transit for that? Because the statement

> "If you provide a transportation service that is open to the public,
>   and operates with fixed schedules and routes, we welcome your
>   participation"

in Google's documentation on

> "Why Google Maps?"

So in this case my website can only be accessible by our university persons, and I think it may violet Google's policy. And second question,

- If I implement this is it accessible from any place other than my website? If it is, then it will become meaning less for those who are not our university persons and so may cause nasty situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About Q1:（May I use Google transit for that? ...）
You might be able to use Google transit by using Google Maps Directions API(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/).
But, there are several limitations. Transportation agency must be in a supported city(http://www.google.com/landing/transit/cities/index.html) and a public transportation agencies(https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/).

About Q2:（If I implement this is it accessible ...）
Other peoples may access your transit feed info. 
But, there are Quality Assurance Review(https://support.google.com/transitpartners/answer/1106422?hl=en&ref_topic=1095593) about the info before launch it.

Comment: The city where I want to implement this is uncovered. But I will manage it. Thank you so much @adjuremods.